# How to open PDF file in JavaScript on Hyperlink click?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

My PDF has a file path like "\IPAddress\Folder\File name",which is coming from DataBase..while JavaScript showing error "Not able to load local resource file".

Comment: Store the pdf on a server. Browsers can't mess around in client's local file system.

Comment: Actually that is a server only but its network path is saved in DB.

Comment: Then add the domain to the beginning of the path.

Comment: If i will put that mentioned path like "\\IPaddress\Foldername\filename" in browser it is opening.But when i will pass this value from JavaScript it will not open.

Comment: In JS you must escape the backslashes. Assuming the path is stored in a variable named `path`, then when adding the "domain", the backslash must be escaped with another backslash, like so: `var url = '\\' + path;`.

Comment: People can only *guess* the solution till you post your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security features of the browser to don't let you access your local file. To accomplish this  you can create a base URL variable in your Javascript file and adjoin with your relative file path i.e

```
let baseURL = "http://192.168.1.48"
```